# IN Asp.net, fixed the sized of browser

Tags: browser

Actually when i run the project browser size appear little smaller which breaks the UI, is there any option to make it fixed sized

Answer (score 1):

If you are speaking of F5 debugging in Visual Studio, you can right click a web document in Solution Explorer and select 'Browse with..' and set default browser size.

BUT- this does not solve your problem when deploying. You cannot control the size of the browser that requests your page.

Your only option for controlling the size of the UI is to use a default document as a bootstrap which uses JavaScript to open a new window of the desired size.

All of that said, If a default browser size is cramping your UI I would have to assume that you have a design crisis.

Good luck.